# How to Implement and Generate ALLURE report with RESTASSURED Framework in Azure DevOps Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, rest-assured, allure

Need your suggestions,
How to Implement and Generate ALLURE report with RESTASSURED Framework in Azure Pipelines.
I have created API Automation in RESTassured framework,
and I have included Allure Java plugins in my Project. I can generate allure plugins on my local machine.
However, how can I create and publish allure reports in Azure DevOps space,
Please guide me and let me know what needs to be done on Azure DevOps side.
do we need to install allure plugins ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, if you can use some tools and related CLI on your local machine to generate and publish the allure report, you can install and use the same tools and CLI to do the same things in Azure DevOps Pipeliens.

---

To configure your project to generate allure report with rest assured, you can reference the article "[Integration of Allure Report with Rest Assured and TestNG](https://qaautomation.expert/2023/10/05/integration-of-allure-report-with-rest-assured-and-testng/)". You generally need to add the **`Allure-Rest Assured dependency`** to the configuration file (such as Maven **`pom.xml`**) of your project.

To integrate Allure with Azure DevOps, you can reference [this article](https://docs.qameta.io/allure-testops/integrations/azure/).

---

In addition, on the [Azure DevOps Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=Allure%20Report&target=AzureDevOps&category=Azure%20Pipelines&sortBy=Relevance), you also can search and find some related extensions that provide the pipeline task to generate and publish the allure report.

---